# Typescript: Can I type enforce a function param as valueof T[key] using another param as key typed keyof T?

Tags: typescript

Given something like:

```
type MyType = {
  key1: string;
  key2: object;
};

function myFunc (param1: keyof MyType, param2: ?)
```

Is it possible to type/enforce `param2` as a type of `MyType[key]` like I could do with `MyType["key2"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Using generics, you can use the key passed as a type parameter, then reference that in `param2`.

```
function myFunc<T extends keyof MyType> (param1: T, param2: MyType[T]) {

}
myFunc('key1', 'foo'); // works
myFunc('key1', 5); // fails
```